# Change size of submenu dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, Razor, JavaScript, DurandalJS. Now my project looks like this:

[image]

I need to change size of my sub-menu drop-down on all with screen size. But I don't know how to make this re-sizing.
I need something like this:

[image]

I must change only background of sub-menu. The text should stay where it is now. How I can make this menu?

Comment: Js fiddle for ur navbar?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/65/ I 
I almost didn't change anything in sub-menu. I need change  background of sub  dropdown menu. Of course the background size should be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with 5% left right is this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wepoc9k/)

```
.dropdown-menu{
   width:90%;
   margin-left:5%;
   top: 30px;
   bottom:0px
}
.dropdown.btn-group.open{
   position:inherit
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is your css change

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/468/)

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0px
}
.dropdown.btn-group.open {
  position: inherit
}
```